# Run php code for each line in database

Tags: php, mysql, cron-task

I want to make some kind of simple way to run a php script for each user in my database.

Until now, i've been doing a cron job, updating every 5 minutes.

I've been using a while to get all users from my database with a certain variable.

```
$henten = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE activated IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($henten)) {
while($visgg = mysql_fetch_array($henten)) {
```

Afterwords it run the php script and update the variable, "activated" to NULL, so the user wont appear in the while anymore.

But my problem is: That if there's a bug in some of the users, and it dont get updated, it will get stocked, so the cron job will all night try to update that certain user, with no luck.

Is there a smarter way to do it?

Comment: First off, don't use mysql functions, use mysqli. The former are depreciated and less secure. What do you mean by "bug in some of the users"? Do you mean that the update might fail?

Comment: Why select users? Why not simply update them?

Comment: @u_mulder Because i need to run a snip of code that withdraw money from the user, and afterwords, if the payment is accepted, then the user gets updated.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Yes, sorry about that. By bugs i mean if the update might fail :-)

Comment: Consider why it might fail, and how you mark that row. If your update is a simple set column = null, it is unlikely to fail.

Comment: But i was wondering if there where another solution, instead of doing cron-job? What about the for each function, could that be a solution?

Comment: Sloan is right. You should use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql,
because mysql is not secure and also has some performance issues. Will you please elaborate on your problem a little bit more?

Comment: My problem is, i want to use another way than cron-jobs to update my users. If there is someway i can open the file and all the users get updated, at the same time, that what be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I have a code Which You can use for your project

```
$q="Select * from products";
$result= mysqli_query($conn,$q) or die("query failed");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$name=$row['brand']." ".$row['model'];
echo $name;
}
```

this way you can access all Products or users in your case and perform any
operation on each user.